# JQ convert UTC datetime to local daylight saving time

Tags: timezone, jq

How to convert UTC datetime to local daylight saving time (AEDT) using JQ (jq-1.6)

`date -d"2023-10-19T04:59:59Z"`

> Thu 19 Oct 2023 15:59:59 AEDT

JQ returns the localtime but not in DST (1 hour extra)

`echo '"2023-10-19T04:59:59Z"' | jq 'fromdate | localtime | todate'`

> "2023-10-19T16:59:59Z"

Also not sure why the time changes right after parsing (1 hour extra)

`echo '"2023-10-19T04:59:59Z"' | jq 'fromdate | todate'`

> "2023-10-19T05:59:59Z"

Comment: There was a [bug](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/1740) in jq 1.6 which was [fixed](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/commit/11c528d04d76c9b9553781aa76b073e4f40da008) in jq 1.7

Comment: Yes, it works in jq 1.7 ```echo '"2023-10-19T04:59:59Z"' | ./jq-linux-i386 'fromdate | localtime | todate'``` thanks a lot @pmf

Comment: could you please create an answer to have this question solved?